# C++ macros generating and error which I can't identify

Tags: c++

Here I was just practicing on macros and I tried this but it's generating an error, says expecting and ; but it seems right from me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define REP(i, a, b) for(int i = a, i <= b; i++)

int main()
{
    int i;
//REP showing an error
    REP(i, 0, 6){
        cout << "Hello"<< " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `i` is already declared before. you can remove statement `int i;` and it will run.

Comment: The error is correct.  The `for` syntax you are using expects two `;`.

Comment: in general you should not use macros in c++

Comment: That macro is broken in more ways than the typo of `,` instead of `;`. In the end it just makes your code harder to read and debug.

Comment: @VNVNA -- that aspect of the code is okay. The `int i` inside the `for` is a local variable; it hides the outer `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace  for(int i = a, i <= b; i++)
with   for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)

the ',' symbol after "= a" is wrong, should be semi-colon.